# Why after I use "subset", the filtered data is less than it should be?

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, subset

I want to have "Blancas" and "Sultana" under the "Variete" column.

Why after I use "subset", the filtered data is less than it should be?

Figure 1 is the original data,

[image]

figure 2 is the expected result,

[image]

figure 3 is result I obtained with the code below:
[image]

```
df <- read_excel("R_NLE_FTSW.xlsx")
options(scipen=200)

BLANCAS<-subset(df, Variete==c("Blancas","Sultana"))
view(BLANCAS)
```

It's obvious that some data of BLANCAS are missing.
P.S. And if try it in a sub-sheet, the final result sometimes will be 5 times more!

```
path = "R_NLE_FTSW.xlsx"
df <- map_dfr(excel_sheets(path), 
               ~ read_xlsx(path, sheet = 4))
```

I don't understand why sometimes it's more and sometimes less than the expected result. Can anyone help me? Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you tried `BLANCAS <- subset(df, Variete %in% c("Blancas", "Sultana"))` ? Replacing `==` by `%>%` ?

Comment: It is difficult to tell without reproducible data, though perhaps you have some strings that are not exactly matched up due to whitespace (i.e. instead of `Blancas`, you have `Blancas  `.  Or try using `%in%` instead of `==`. Again, we can't always tell without reproducible data; posting images of data is always discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, while you mention that you need both "Blancas" and "sultanas" , your expected result shows only Blancas! So get that straight first.

For such data comign from excel :

1. Always clean the data after its imported. Check for unqiue values to find if there are any extra spaces etc.
2. Trim the character data, ensure Date fields are correct and numbers are numeric (not characters)
3. Now to subset a data : Use `df%>%filter(Variete %in% c('Blancas','Sultana')`
   -> you can modify the c() vector to include items of interest.
   -> if you wish to clean on the go?

`df%>%filter(trimws(Variete)) %in% c('Blancas','Sultana'))`

and your sub-sheet problem : We even don't know what data is there. If its similar then apply same logics.

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem has solved with `%in%`! I will upload my original data for future question!

Comment: Glad to know that. pls accept the answer if it has worked for you. Will help future users as well.